# Chrome's console takes several seconds to print an integer array element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'll start with creating a 10M size array `a` in Chrome console :

```
n=10000000;
a=[];
for (let i=0;i<n;++i) {a.push(i);};
```

then I want to view value of `a[5]`, so I just input "`a[5]`" in the console.

I would expect the console return "5" immediately. To my surprise it takes about 3 seconds to see "5" on the console, and Chrome process are using nearly 100% of a single cpu core and several hundreds MegaBytes of memory during that 3 seconds time.

if I keep inputing "a[5]" in the console. After several "slow response", it will be OK. At that time a[6],a[100],a[999999] are also OK. But "a[1]+a[2]"-- very slow again. It seems that for every expression structure there will be some "warm up time".

EDIT: when slow response occur, the profiler shows like this:

```
6114.8 ms 78.31 %   6115.5 ms 78.32 %   getCompletions(program):1   
777.5 ms 9.96 % 777.5 ms 9.96 % (garbage collector) 
708.8 ms 9.08 % 792.3 ms 10.15 %    getCompletions(program):1   
106.6 ms 1.37 % 106.6 ms 1.37 % (program)
```

Why an array access and display command triggers several seconds execution of "getCompletions"?

Info:
I have Chrome (53.0.2785.143 m (Windows 64-bit)) and 8GB RAM.

Comment: have you profiled it?  What does the profiler say?

Comment: `So what is Chrome doing behind the scene` the loop you told it to do. It won't run anything until it finishes it, since it runs your JS code single threaded.

Comment: @xaxxon the profiler said "getCompletions" are using CPU, but I am doing simple array access and does not write "getCompletions", I am finding the reason Chrome doing so.

Comment: @vlaz If the loop is lazy evaluated util the first array access, all subsequential should be quick. But in my test, subsequential  access can be slow too.

Comment: @user2218067 _if_ it's lazy evaluated. But it isn't. Or do you believe it is and if so, why?

Comment: @vlaz I thought you comment means "when you input a[5] and hit enter, the loop is still in progress" so I thought you were talking about lazy evaluation. Sorry for not describing the case clearly.  It was "after the loop complete, I input a[5], "5" is displayed after several seconds. I thought it should display immediately"